# Get time when Chrome extension's "Allow in incognito" is turned on\off

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, incognito-mode

I need to get the time when my Chrome extension's "Allow in incognito" mode is turned on\off.

I know about `chrome.extension.isAllowedIncognitoAccess()`. But I would need to check each few seconds with this function. Is there any more ellegant way, like some event listener?

I also tried inserting content script into `chrome://extensions` page and registering each time someone checks\unchecks that chechbox for allowing in incognito, but it's not allowed to inject scripts into this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, no.

There isn't any event that would fire when this permission is changed - neither in `chrome.extension` API, nor in `chrome.management` API (in fact, this permission is not exposed to `management` API at all).

Comment: I would have said "Happily, no". It's a good thing that extensions can't know when you are in private mode. It protects your confidentiality.

Comment: @lovasoa Oh no, you can absolutely tell if you're running in an incognito tab once the access is granted. This is specifically for event-based detection of the grant.

Comment: I'm going to run chrome.extension.isAllowedIncognitoAccess() in background.js each X seconds then.. thanks for your input @Xan !